# How do you remove custom values from request headers?

Tags: angular, http-headers, httprequest

I am using angular 8. 
I'd like to remove a custom value in  HttpConceptor() based on a condition.

```
intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    if(...){
     const newHeaders = request.headers.delete('abc', '123');
     const newRequest = request.clone({headers: newHeaders});
    }

    ...
    return next.handle(newRequest)
```

But the delete() meothd does not remove the value "abc", the below is newHeaders' JSON value

```
{
  "normalizedNames": {},
  "lazyUpdate": [
    {
      "name": "abc",
      "value": "123",
      "op": "s"
    },
    {
      "name": "abc",
      "value": "123",
      "op": "d"
    }
  ],
  "headers": {},
  "lazyInit": {
    "normalizedNames": {},
    "lazyUpdate": null,
    "headers": {}
  }
}
```

Thanks.

Update:
The original headers of the request:

```
{
  "normalizedNames": {},
  "lazyUpdate": [
    {
      "name": "abc",
      "value": "123",
      "op": "s"
    }
  ],
  "headers": {},
  "lazyInit": {
    "normalizedNames": {},
    "lazyUpdate": null,
    "headers": {}
  }
}
```

Comment: 'abc' and '123' are values, you have to access the object items by keys, not values.

Comment: Not exactly. According to Angular docs, the second parameter of delete method is an optional value.
https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpHeaders#delete

delete(name: string, value?: string | string[]):